# Python/Math Find Previous Value in Fibonacci Sequence with a Function/Equation

Tags: numbers, fibonacci

This is slightly less code related...
I am making a function that calculates a Fibonacci number backwards.

Not just print it backwards but do the math itself backwards.
I did a little research using Phi and phi...

I think I mostly got it,
 but how do I calculate a previous number in the sequence?

I.E. F6 is 8 and F5 is 5. I need a function to find "5" (The previous number).

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
    def FingFactorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        res = n * FingFactorial(n-1)
        return res
n=int(input("Factorial Of : "))
print("Factorial Of",n,"Is :",FingFactorial(n-1))
```

this code may give your desired result .. :) [CLICK HERE THIS MAY HELP YOU](http://blog.iamovi.me/function-in-python/)

Comment: Thanks! Wow that was quick! I'm new to code so could you explain a little about this p!ease? (If you have time =)

Comment: I tried that and that was not what I wanted at all. I did a little more research, and created the code below:

Comment: 'import math #Imports python math library

Phi = ((1 + math.sqrt(5))/2) # defines Phi, the golden ratio
phi = ((1 - math.sqrt(5))/2)

def rfib(n): #Creates the function, short for Reverse Fibonacci
    for i in range(n):
        num = n - i #Counts backwards from n
        print(round(((Phi**num)-(phi**num))/math.sqrt(5))) #Prints rounded equation.'

Answer (score 0):

```
import math #Imports python math library

Phi = ((1 + math.sqrt(5))/2) # defines Phi, the golden ratio phi = ((1
- math.sqrt(5))/2)

def rfib(n): #Creates the function, short for Reverse Fibonacci
    for i in range(n):
        num = n - i #Counts backwards from n
        print(round(((Phi**num)-(phi**num))/math.sqrt(5))) #Prints equation.
```